# MATLAB: cumulative geometric mean

Tags: matlab, geometric-mean

I have a 2x3 matrix `m = [1.1, 2.0, 0.5 ; 0.9, 1.5, 1.1];`. I need to compute a cumulative geometric mean along the second dimension, i.e. the resulting matrix `results` must also have the same dimension (2x3). It's basically comparable to using `cumprod` with the extensions that I need to take the 1/n power where `n` is the column number.

`results` must look like this:

```
[(1.1)^(1/1), (1.1 * 2.0)^(1/2), (1.1 * 2.0 * 0.5)^(1/3) ;
 (0.9)^(1/1), (0.9 * 1.5)^(1/2), (0.9 * 1.5 * 1.1)^(1/3)]
```

`results = cumprod(m,2)` delivers the multiplication components. However, what's the most clever way in order to take the appropriate powers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the *power* of [`bsxfun`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) -

```
bsxfun(@power, cumprod(m,2), 1./(1:size(m,2)))
```

Sample run -

```
>> m
m =
    1.1000    2.0000    0.5000
    0.9000    1.5000    1.1000
>> bsxfun(@power, cumprod(m,2), 1./(1:size(m,2)))
ans =
    1.1000    1.4832    1.0323
    0.9000    1.1619    1.1409
>> [(1.1)^(1/1), (1.1 * 2.0)^(1/2), (1.1 * 2.0 * 0.5)^(1/3) ;
    (0.9)^(1/1), (0.9 * 1.5)^(1/2), (0.9 * 1.5 * 1.1)^(1/3)]
ans =
    1.1000    1.4832    1.0323
    0.9000    1.1619    1.1409
```

On newer MATLAB versions, with `implicit-expansion`, the expression would simplify to -

```
cumprod(m,2).^ (1./(1:size(m,2)))
```

Comment: Follow-up question:
What if I need to take the cumulated geometric mean along the first dimension, i.e.
    bsxfun(@power, cumprod(m,1), 1./(1:size(m,1)))?
However, this results in a dimension error:
"Error using bsxfun
Non-singleton dimensions of the two input arrays must
match each other."

Comment: @Andi Try : `bsxfun(@power, cumprod(m,1),  [1./(1:size(m,1))]' )`.